# Duration time to execute in PHP

Tags: php, execute

I need to program something in PHP but i have to know execution time between my line 5 and my line 14.

The problem is that i don't find anything to do what i want (calculate execution time between that lines).

How can i synchronize it with another action ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made a post about it on my website after some search.

You can add before :

```
$mtime = microtime();
$mtime = explode(" ",$mtime);
$mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
$starttime = $mtime;
```

And after your code :

```
$mtime = microtime();
$mtime = explode(" ",$mtime);
$mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
$endtime = $mtime;
$totaltime = ($endtime - $starttime);
echo "Executed in ".$totaltime." seconds";
```

What do you mean by synchonizing it ? Launching something else ? Be more precise for that part.

Comment: Since PHP 5.0 you can use `microtime(true)`

Answer (score 15):

Just use [microtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php),

**Here is a simple example:**

```
<?php
//get initial start time
$time_start = microtime(true);

//then do your php goodness... 

//get script end time
$time_end = microtime(true);

//calculate the difference between start and stop
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

//echo it 
echo "Did whatever in $time seconds\n";
?>
```

Or something like this:

```
<?php
//get initial start time
$time_start = microtime(true);

//then do your php goodness...
sleep(2);

//echo it
echo sprintf("Did whatever in %.3f seconds", (float)microtime(true)-$time_start);
?>
```